# CUPS printing remote(http://) files from command line

Tags: linux, unix, command-line, cups

I am trying to create a custom script to control my `CANON SELPHY PRINTER` form the command-line.

`lp -d Canon_CP900 -o media="CP_C_size" /Users/sangyookim/Desktop/selphy.jpg`

I have the tested the above code and it's working perfectly as I intend it to.

But I have stumbled upon a problem.

When I replace the `/Users/sangyookim/Desktop/selphy.jpg` or `filname` to a web link such as the below, it will return me `unable to access.. No such file or directory`

`http://res.cloudinary.com/splexz/image/upload/v1447239237/yer60xuvd6nmeldcbivd.png`

How can I print images from the web using `CUPS command line`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly print a remote web page (because most Linux commands, `lp` included, do not know about URLs).

At least, you'll need to first fetch that web page using a command line HTTP client like [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) or [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/), then use another command (with `lp` or `lpr`) to print it (and perhaps later remove that downloaded file from your local filesystem).

For images, you probably would need some converter before printing them, e.g. the `convert` command from [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) (which happens to understand URLs, thanks to [Mark Setchell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2836621/mark-setchell) for commenting on this), to convert them to some `.pdf` or perhaps `.ps` file (unless you have configured `lp` or CUPS to do the conversion automagically). Maybe you could use [a2ps](https://www.gnu.org/software/a2ps/)

You could write some script (or shell function) to do all the job.

In limited cases, you might also consider using some network file systems [NFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System), [CIFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block) or set up some [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) (I don't recommend that).

Comment: Just a minor clarification... ImageMagick does understand URLs on its command line, so you can do things like `convert http://someserver.com/images/xyz.png localImage.pdf`